# Flask url with variable input

Tags: python, flask

Im trying to get my button to redirect to a route in my program with some variable values to dynamically generate a pdf, the pdf generation works by itself but when i submit the form instead of going to `genreport/{{lid}/{{userID}}` 
i go to `genreport//?userID=3`

The code for my form

```
<form action="/genreport/{{lid}}/{{userID}}">
          <input type="number" placeholder="ID" id="userID" name="userID">
      <select>
          <option value="1" id="lid" name="lid">{{letter.description}}</option>
      </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Generate Report">
      </form>
  </div>
```

The code for my route

```
@app.route('/genreport/<lid>/<userID>')
def pdf_template():
    lid = request.form['lid']
    userID = request.form['userID']
    policy = Policy.query.get(request.form[userID])
    letter = Letter.query.get(request.form[lid])
    rendered = render_template_string(letter.template, policy=policy, lid=lid, userID=userID)
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False)

    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=output.pdf'

    return response
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated as i have spent a good amount of time on this issue. If any more information is needed i can provide it.

EDIT

Here are all the routes of my application with the changes i have made since i posted the question

```
@app.route('/')
@login_required
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/reports', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def reports():
    if request.method == "GET":
        return render_template('reports.html')
    letter = Letter.query.get(1)
    first = request.form['searchFirst']
    contact = Contact.query.filter_by(first=first).first()
    return render_template('results.html', contact=contact, letter=letter)


@app.route('/results', methods=['GET','POST'])
@login_required
def results():
    return render_template('results.html')


@app.route('/management')
@login_required
def management():
    return render_template('management.html')


@app.route('/history')
@login_required
def history():
    return render_template('history.html')


@app.route('/settings')
@login_required
def settings():
    return render_template('settings.html')


@app.route('/login', methods=['GET','POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('login.html')
    username = request.form['inputEmail']
    password = request.form['inputPassword']
    remember_me = False
    if 'remember_me' in request.form:
        remember_me = True
    registered_user = User.query.filter_by(username=username, password=password).first()
    if registered_user is None:
        flash('Username or Password is invalid', 'error')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    login_user(registered_user, remember=remember_me)
    flash('Logged in Successfully')
    return redirect(request.args.get('next') or url_for('index'))


@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    logout_user()
    return redirect(url_for('index'))


@app.route('/signup', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def signup():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        return render_template('signup.html')
    user = User(request.form['inputFirst'], request.form['inputLast'], request.form['inputEmail'], request.form['dob'], request.form['inputPassword', request.form['inputStreet'],request.form['inputState'],request.form['inputCity'],request.form['inputZip'],request.form['inputPhone']])
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('User successfully created!')
    return redirect(url_for('login'))


@app.route('/profile/<name>')
@login_required
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html', name=name)


@app.route('/admin')
@login_required
def admin():
    return render_template('admin.html')


@app.route('/genreport/<lid>/<id>')
def pdf_template():
    policy = Policy.query.get(request.form['userID'])
    letter = Letter.query.get(request.form['lid'])
    rendered = render_template_string(letter.template, policy=policy, letter=letter)
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False)

    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=output.pdf'

    return response
```

Comment: @trevor add the template for that render your form

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you using parametrizing url you can use function with parameters:

```
# url to call will be:
# genreport/1/2
@app.route('/genreport/<lid>/<userID>')
def pdf_template(lid, userID):
    print(lid, userID)
    # lid = request.form['lid']
    # userID = request.form['userID']
```

Second option use url parameters, you should use request.args.get:

```
# url to call will be:
# genreport?lid=1&userID=2
@app.route('/genreport')
def pdf_template():
    lid = request.args.get('lid')
    userID = request.args.get('userID')
    print(lid, userID)
```

Comment: The second option was the one that worked and it worked beautifully so thank you for all the help I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use [url_for](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.url_for)  to build urls for your forms

what you need in your form is:

```
<form action="{{url_for('app.pdf_template', userID=1, lid=1)}}">
          <input type="number" placeholder="ID" id="userID" name="userID">
      <select>
          <option value="1" id="lid" name="lid">{{letter.description}}</option>
      </select>
          <input type="submit" value="Generate Report">
      </form>
  </div>
```

and the route :

```
@app.route('/genreport/<lid>/<userID>')
def pdf_template(lid, userID):
    lid = request.form[lid]
    userID = request.form[userID]
    policy = Policy.query.get(userId)
    letter = Letter.query.get(lid)
    rendered = render_template_string(letter.template, policy=policy, lid=lid, userID=userID)
    pdf = pdfkit.from_string(rendered, False)

    response = make_response(pdf)
    response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/pdf'
    response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline; filename=output.pdf'

    return response
```